# Error CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException on SQLite when fast querying

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm querying from SQLite with field ID and 8 field Strings (some are nullable).
I have a method getSearchedItemsFromSQLite that is triggered whenever there is a change state on an EditText object (auto search) and these error message randomly appears but the app is not crashing at all.

```
    07-27 18:24:52.619: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1173): ERROR: thread attach failed
    07-27 18:24:55.188: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1184): ERROR: thread attach failed
    07-27 18:25:18.649: ERROR/GuitarTabs(1191): getSearchedItemsFromSQLite: Handler for DB + cursor: Index 6 requested, with a size of 6


    07-27 18:25:18.659: WARN/System.err(1191): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 requested, with a size of 6
    07-27 18:25:18.889: WARN/System.err(1191):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
    07-27 18:25:18.889: WARN/System.err(1191):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
    07-27 18:25:18.889: WARN/System.err(1191):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
    07-27 18:25:18.889: WARN/System.err(1191):     at com.package.project.activity.ItemBrowserActivity.getSearchedItemsFromSQLite(ItemBrowserActivity.java:351)
    07-27 18:25:18.889: WARN/System.err(1191):     at com.package.project.activity.ItemBrowserActivity$AppInitialization.doInBackground(ItemBrowserActivity.java:199)
    07-27 18:25:18.889: WARN/System.err(1191):     at com.package.project.activity.ItemBrowserActivity$AppInitialization.doInBackground(ItemBrowserActivity.java:1)
    07-27 18:25:18.889: WARN/System.err(1191):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    07-27 18:25:18.899: WARN/System.err(1191):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    07-27 18:25:18.909: WARN/System.err(1191):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    07-27 18:25:18.909: WARN/System.err(1191):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    07-27 18:25:18.909: WARN/System.err(1191):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
    07-27 18:25:18.909: WARN/System.err(1191):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

How can I resolve this?

Here's a code snippet of the method:

```
        dbHelper.open();
        cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllTabs(fetchMethod);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    if(cursor.getColumnCount() > 0) {
                        Log.i(logAppName, "/ - Column count is:  " + cursor.getColumnCount());
                        if(!cursor.isNull(0) && !cursor.isNull(1)) {
                            if(!cursor.isNull(0)) {
                                ListedItem tab = new ListedItem();
                                tab.setSongID(cursor.getInt(0));
                                if(!cursor.isNull(1)) tab.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                                if(!cursor.isNull(2)) tab.setArtist(cursor.getString(2));
                                if(!cursor.isNull(3)) tab.setDifficulty(cursor.getString(3));
                                if(!cursor.isNull(4)) tab.setGenre(cursor.getString(4));
                                if(!cursor.isNull(5)) tab.setFilename(cursor.getString(5));
                                if(!cursor.isNull(6)) tab.setFileformat(cursor.getString(6));
                                if(!cursor.isNull(7)) tab.setSource(cursor.getString(7));
                                if(!cursor.isNull(8)) tab.setDeleted(cursor.getString(8));
                                if(Integer.parseInt(tab.getDeleted()) == 0)
                                    ret.add(tab);
                                else 
                                    Log.i(logAppName, "Not adding tab: " + tab.getSongTitle() + " (" + tab.getSongFilename() + ") " + "since it's already deleted.");
                                cursor.moveToNext();
                            } else {
                                Log.i(logAppName, "x - ID is null.");
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.i(logAppName, "x - Either id or title is null.");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.i(logAppName, "x - Column count is:  " + cursor.getColumnCount());
                    }
                }
            }      
            if(cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
```

Comment: Well, according to the error message, your cursor tries to access index 6, but your cursor only contains indices [0,5]. Check your query, to see that it actually returns the number of columns you need. What's the output of your: Log.i(logAppName, "/ - Column count is: " + cursor.getColumnCount())

Comment: I think the reason behind this is that on fast querying, when I enter a then u in the editText it always calls the query method whenever editText's value changes, hence, method never really finishes processing when it's called again.

This error only occurs on emulator, I've tested this on devices and I couldn't reproduce the error at all.

Is there any limitation on emulator where SQLite is concerned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added these conditions:

```
if ( cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 ) { 
    totalRows = cursor.getCount();
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
        if(cursor.getColumnCount() > 0) {
               ...
```

After that, I added a sleep thread to allow previous process to finish first before going through another process:

```
private boolean processing = false;
...

int ctr = 0;
// added fix to avoid error on cursor
while(processing) {
    try {
    Log.i(logAppName, "Still processing. Count: " + ctr + ". Is processing? " + processing);
        ctr++;
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(ctr > 5) {
        break;
    }
}
```